# Show that $\langle(1234),(12)\rangle = S_4$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I am trying to show that $\langle(1234),(12)\rangle = S_4$. I can multiply and get all $24$ permutations manually but isn't there a more compact solution?

Comment: Related MO [thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24101/natural-generating-sets-for-symmetric-groups).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write $H$ for the subgroup generated by those two permutations. Then $(1234)(12)=(234)$, so $H$ contains certainly the elements of $\langle(1234)\rangle$, $\langle (234)\rangle$ and $(12)$, hence $\vert H\vert \geq 7$ and therefore $\vert H\vert \geq 8$ ($\vert H\vert$ must divide $24=\vert S_{4}\vert$). Since $(1234)\in H$ but such a permutation is not even, i.e it doesn't belong to $A_{4}$, $H$ is not a subgroup of $A_{4}$. By Lagrange's theorem, $\vert H\vert$ must equal $24$ (the only subgroup of order $12$ in $S_{4}$ is $A_{4}$) and we're done.

Comment: It should be $(12)(1234) = (243)$.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if this a more "compact" solution, but this follows from a more general result that the $\langle (123\ldots n),(12) \rangle = S_{n}$, which I think would be cleaner and more instructive to show. Hint: see if you can show that this subgroup generates all transpositions in $S_{n}$, and therefore generates $S_{n}$.

Answer (score 5):

Conjugate $(12)$ by powers of $(1234)$ to get $(12), (23), (34)$. Then, you can conjugate further to get all transpositions.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you are familiar to $S_4$ presentation:
$$S_4=\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^4=(ab)^3=1\rangle$$ Considering a nice Corollary of Von Dyck's Theorem we can set $a=(1,2),~~~b=(1,2,3,4)$ and see that $(ab)^3=1,a^2=b^4=1$. Also, an small program in GAP's environment could show this fast and easy:

```
gap> f:=FreeGroup("a","b");
gap> a:=f.1;; b:=f.2;; 
     s:=f/[a^4,b^2,(a*b)^3];;
gap> StructureDescription(s);
                                         "S4"
```

Comment: @amWhy: I pray for them to defeat it.

Comment: They're in good hands, since you have taught them well, I am sure!

Answer (score 2):

The two methods I would use are either

- show all transpositions appear. If $c$ is the cycle and $t$ the transposition, start by considering $c^{-1}tc$.
- note that we have an element of order 4 already, and multiplying the ones we have together gives an element of order 3. Hence the group generated has order divisible by 12. But the only subgroup of size 12 is $A_4$ which this clearly is not.

Comment: On bullet point number 2, why is it that the group generated must have order divisible by 12 when we have elements of order 4 and order 3?

Comment: oh would it be if |f| = 4 and |g| = 3 then <f> is a cyclic subgroup of order 4 and <g> is a cyclic subgroup of order 3 then since both are subgroups of <f,g>, and each must divide <f,g>, then $|<f,g>|$ $\ge$  lcm(4,3) = 12?

Comment: @H_1317 I wouldn't write $\ge$ there, as the result is stronger, it's a *multiple* of 12. But yes, an order $n$ element defines an $n$ element subgroup, and by Lagrange's theorem the order of the group is a multiple of $n$. Thus the given group has order divisible by the LCM of 3 and 4, which is indeed 12.